# JavaFX on ActionEvent dynamically add / remove Node

Tags: java, javafx

I build a simple JavaFX App and I wan't to create a circle in the center of an ellipse when the Mouse enters the ellipse.

This is some of the Code:

```
ellipse = new Ellipse(30,30,40,40);
ellipse.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
ellipse.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

ellipse.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    circle.setCenterX(30);
    circle.setCenterY(30);
    circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    group.getChildren().add(circle);
    group.getChildren().removeAll(ellipse);

    System.out.println("Added Circle");
});

group = new Group();
group.getChildren().add(ellipse);
vBox = new VBox();
vBox.getChildren().add(group);
```

The Vbox is added to a Scene and the Scene is added to the PrimaryStage.

If I run the program and my Mouse enters the ellipse the ellipse will be removed but the circle will not be added.

Can anyone explain me why? 
First of all this seems to be the wrong way of implementing an dynamic node Adding / removing thing. What would be the right way? 
But I'm also interested in why can I remove a Node so easy but I can't added it so easy?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and include a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, the Circle has no radius... 
If I add a radius to the circle everything works fine,